# + draw to the center of the picture in Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, octave

I want to draw 4 pixels + black on the picture so that it passes right in the middle of the picture, which commands do I need to use?[image]

i know we will use loop but i couldn't create its algorithm.

Comment: I don't think you'll need a loop, but it would help if you could post the code you're using to draw the image.  That's going to influence the correct solution.

Comment: `for m=1:en
 I(m,boy/2)=0;
 I(m,boy/2-1)=0;
 I(m,boy/2+1)=0;
end`

Comment: Equivalently without a loop: `I(:,boy/2-1:boy/2+1) = 0`. But please do not use comments to add details to your question, and edit the question instead.